# install openssl-devel on Mac

Tags: macos, openssl

I need to install the openssl-devel on Mac. But I've tried brew and macport both. Neither of them work.

And I have also googled this problem--- install openssl-devel on Mac. But, I did not find an exact answer.

Anyone met this kind of problem before?

Comment: Me too facing the same issue. I need it to compile `xrdp` for Mac. For now we have to go with http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/openssl/

Comment: Question seems closely related to "CMake not able to find OpenSSL library". Here's the answer pertaining to MacOS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69268455/1965146

Answer (score 22):

This has changed with the latest verison of brew on Big Sur (11.5.1) on a Macbook M1 (just for completeness):

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"
```

Comment: If you're using CMake, this answer is closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69268455/1965146

Comment: Replacing openssl@3 with openssl1.1 ended up working for me

Comment: What is the meaning of the word "this" ?

Answer (score 9):

this command solve my problem:

```sh
brew install openssl@1.1
cp /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig/*.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/
```

Comment: I have been following the thrift installation tutorial which led me to this comment by @AndyTao. For me version 1.1 did not work as it conflicted with some rubygems.

sudo cp /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0/lib/pkgconfig/*.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/

Copy version 1.0 of openSSL

Comment: I would prefer the other solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65287219/314725), cleaner than potentially overwriting something in the pkgconfig folder ...

Comment: Thank you!!! After hours of reinstalls and dead ends, copying that pkgconfig folder finally allowed me to install openssl -> tidyverse in RStudio.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you want to compile C++ program, and the C++ code include openssl headers, so just install openssl with `brew`:

```
brew install openssl
```

or install openssl 1.1.1 with

```
brew install openssl@1.1
```

Then you can find `include` and `lib` folder in `/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0/` or `/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1`, and adjust your makefile, modify the path like this:

```
OPENSSL_DIR = /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1
OPENSSL_SUPPORT = -I$(OPENSSL_DIR)/include -L$(OPENSSL_DIR)/lib
```

Answer (score 2):

```
brew install openssl@1.1
```

Don't copy anything, just set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable with the path to openssl's *.pc files:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig/
```

Comment: This worked better, but with `openssl@3`

Answer (score 1):

`brew install openssl@1.1`

`cd /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/`

[make symbolic links instead of copying](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html)

`cp --symbolic-link /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig/* .`

Symlinks are now in the present working directory.