# 'openssl/crypto.h' file not found on vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I got the following compile error even though I added the include path to openssl. I'm using vscode on a MAC. Can you tell me how to fix it?

**Error**

```
main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'openssl/crypto.h' file not found
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <openssl/crypto.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hoge" << endl;
}
```

**.vscode/tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "g++",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-std=c++14", "-O2", "-l", "boost_system", "-l", "boost_thread", "-o", "test", "-g",
        "main.cpp"
    ],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

**.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": "",
                "path": [
                    "/usr/include",
                    "/usr/local/include",
                    "/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json**

```
$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl

$ ls  /usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl | grep crypto.h
crypto.h
```

---

Update 1

I found the similar issue but still did not find the solution for me yet.

[Compiling C programs using libssl on OS X El Capitan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33530865/compiling-c-programs-using-libssl-on-os-x-el-capitan)

[How to use OpenSSL with GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894013/how-to-use-openssl-in-gcc)

http://qiita.com/marumaru/items/ca801c957986302f6fe6

---

Update 2

I tried to compile using g++ but it did not work too. My mac is OS X El Capitan version10.11.6

```
$ g++ main.cpp -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o test
main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'openssl/crypto.h' file not found
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

---

Update 3

Problem solved. I added -I and -L options.

```
g++ main.cpp -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o test
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:
On Mac (but this should work on other OSs as well), I first updated openssl:

```
brew upgrade openssl
```

Then setup the following env variables:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

Which I got by simply trying:

```
brew info openssl
```

I still had to update tasks.json, but now the changes worked (clang for c):

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clang build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include",
                "-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib",
                "-lssl",
                "-lcrypto"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```