# VSCode, MacOS Catalina - doesn't stop on breakpoints on C/C++ debug

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, xcode11, vscode-debugger, macos-catalina

I'm trying to make breakpoints work on C code developed using VSCode on Mac.

My code seems to compile and run just fine (thanks to ['openssl/crypto.h' file not found on vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361462/openssl-crypto-h-file-not-found-on-vscode/58323678#58323678) B.T.W) but I don't get any breakpoints, not even on start using `"stopAtEntry": true` or by attaching to a running process.

My `tasks.json` and `launch.json` are very standard:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clang build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include",
                "-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib",
                "-lssl",
                "-lcrypto"
            ],
            "options": {
               "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

And:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Attach",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test2",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        },
        {
            "name": "clang build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "clang build active file",
            "logging": {
                "trace": false,
                "traceResponse": false,
                "engineLogging": false
              }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm aware of [VS code is ignoring the breakpoint in c++ debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268226/vs-code-is-ignoring-the-breakpoint-in-c-debugging) and all of the similar discussions here.

My setup is:
MacOS Catalina (10.15, production) alongside XCode 11.1, Visual Studio Code 1.39.0 and C/C++ extension 0.26.0-insiders3.

Has anyone had better luck than me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So apparently it's a known issue with Catalina and XCode 11.x support: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3829 caused by `lldb-mi`.

`lldb-mi` is the driver that [sits between the IDE and the lldb API itself](https://www.codeplay.com/portal/lldb-mi-driver---part-1-introduction).

It appears that the version of `lldb-mi` that comes bundled with the plugin isn't compatible with Catalina, and XCode 11.x doesn't have `lldb-mi` anymore.

The github thread offers 2 temporary solutions:

### lldb-mi

The first solution is to use the `lldb-mi` that comes bundled with previous versions of XCode, by setting the `miDebuggerPath` property of `launch.json`.

I happened to have XCode 10.1 lying around so my configuration is:

```
"miDebuggerPath":"/Applications/Xcode 10.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/lldb-mi",
```

I managed to get basic debugging working but there are [compatibility issues to be expected](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3829#issuecomment-539746166). However this turned out to be good enough for my needs (yay!).

### A replacement lldb frontend

The second solution is to use the [VSCode-lldb extension](https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb).

### Updates come here

I will keep this answer and this [post](https://www.devsbedevin.net/vscode-debugging-c-cpp-code-on-macos-catalina/) updated with a permanent solution once it comes up.

Answer (score 5):

Follow on @Vaiden solution 2, which I carry on with my C++ vscode debugging. I supplement how on use it on my debugging configuration.

1. **Install CodeLLDB vscode extension**
2. **Modify launch.json configuration file**

> ```
> {
>   "version": "0.2.0",
>   "configurations": [
>       {
>           //...other configuration
>           "type": "lldb", // change this one from cppdbg to lldb
>       }
>   ]
> }
> ```

3. **F5 to start debug your code, and it should fix your lldm-mi issue**