# cmake can not find openssl on windows

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, openssl

I already read this post and it did not answer my questions: ([cmake not able to find openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248775/cmake-not-able-to-find-openssl))

I am working in windows 10 64 bit and I want to use boost asio with ssl support, so I installed openssl in C:\Local\OpenSSL-Win64 and I have a environment variable pointing to this.

I have this code in cmake:

```
file(TO_CMAKE_PATH $ENV{OPENSSL_ROOT} OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR)
message(WARNING "root: ${OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR}")
find_package(OpenSSL )

message(WARNING "OpenSSL_VERSION: ${OPENSSL_VERSION}")
message(WARNING "OpenSSL_INCLUDE_DIR: ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message(WARNING "OpenSSL_LIBRARIES: ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}")
```

and when I run the cmake, I am getting this message:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:44 (message):
  root: C:/Local/OpenSSL-Win64


CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:293 (list):
  list GET given empty list
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:45 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:294 (list):
  list GET given empty list
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:45 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:296 (list):
  list GET given empty list
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:45 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:298 (list):
  list GET given empty list
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:45 (find_package)


Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing:  OPENSSL_LIBRARIES) (found version ".0.0`")
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:47 (message):
  OpenSSL_VERSION: .0.0`


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:48 (message):
  OpenSSL_INCLUDE_DIR: C:/Local/OpenSSL-Win64/include


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:49 (message):
  OpenSSL_LIBRARIES: SSL_EAY_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND;LIB_EAY_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
```

as it can be seen the cmake could find the environment variable which is correctly pointed to C:/Local/OpenSSL-Win64

also interestingly, it can find the include path:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:48 (message):
OpenSSL_INCLUDE_DIR: C:/Local/OpenSSL-Win64/include
```

but the version, and include library is not right.

is there any specific ways that I can force cmake to find the openssl?

How can I make sure that it finds the suitable static library?

## Edit 1

Aftre upgrading to cmake 3.8, now, cmake can find openssl, but not its libraries. The output is as follow:

```
Found OpenSSL: C:/Local/OpenSSL-Win64/lib/libssl.lib (found version "1.1.0e") 
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:52 (message):
  OpenSSL_VERSION: 1.1.0e


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:53 (message):
  OpenSSL_INCLUDE_DIR: C:/Local/OpenSSL-Win64/include


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:54 (message):
  OpenSSL_LIBRARIES:
```

Why libraries are not found?

## Edit 2

The reason that it could not find library was that I used the variable name with a different case. The correct name is OPENSSL_LIBRARIES.

For more information read the findopenssl.cmake file as part of the cmake distribution.

Comment: What version of OpenSSL do you have and what version of CMake are you using? More recent OpenSSL versions changed the format of how the version number is specified in their header and a corresponding change in CMake was needed to account for that. Perhaps try the latest CMake release (currently 3.8.0) and see if that fixes your issue. If it does, I'll turn this comment into an answer for you.

Comment: @CraigScott It helped a lot, but did not fixed the problem completely. See my updated question.

Comment: @CraigScott Now I managed to fix the problem. I mixed the case on library . Please turn your comment to answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More recent OpenSSL versions (the 1.1.x series I think) slightly changed the formatting of how the version number was specified in the `opensslv.h` header. This caused CMake's version parsing code in its `FindOpenSSL.cmake` module to fail, which was then fixed around CMake 3.5.0. Furthermore, from OpenSSL 1.1.0, the library names on Windows are closer to their Unix counterparts and are named libcrypto and libssl (possibly with further suffixes) instead of the old names libeay32 and ssleay32. CMake 3.7.0 contained the update to account for this library name change. As a result of these two changes and fixes, if you want to use OpenSSL 1.1.0 or later with a CMake project, you should probably be using CMake 3.7.0 or later.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem with cmake 2.8.12.2 and OpenSSL 1.0.2u

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:278 (list):
  list GET given empty list
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:169 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

To find out more details, you can add "--debug-output" option to cmake command.

In our case, it helped to specify the -D_OPENSSL_VERSION on cmake command line:

```
OPENSSL_VER=1.0.2u

cmake ...
  -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=$IDIR_BASE \
  -DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=$IDIR_BASE/include \
  -D_OPENSSL_VERSION="$OPENSSL_VER" \
```