# Compile libssh2 based C code (and generate the exe) on windows

Tags: windows, libssh2

I could successfully build the libssh2 library for windows using [Compiling libssh2 on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44889540/compiling-libssh2-on-windows). I am not able to figure out  the command to compile a simple C program on a windows system that uses libssh2 , say any example code from https://libssh2.org/examples/

My system: Windows Server 2019, Visual studio 2017.

Command I tried:
cl ssh2_exec.c

Error: cannot open include file : 'libssh2.h': no such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Try and type first:

```
set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;C:\path\to\libssh2-headers\folder
```

Then try again your `cl ssh2_exec.c`: that should be enough for `cl` to find where the header files are.