# How Can I use CPR library with Android(NDK)?

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, openssl

I am trying to use [CPR](https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr) in android. This is my `src/main/cpp` directory's structure:

```
cpr/ 
native-lib.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
```

note: cpr/ directory is generated by running this command `git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr.git`

And this is the content of `CMakeLists.txt` in `src/main/cpp` directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
add_library(
        native-lib
        SHARED
        native-lib.cpp
)
find_library(
        log-lib
        log
)

add_subdirectory(cpr)
target_link_libraries(
        native-lib
        cpr
        ${log-lib}
)
```

But I get this error when I build and run the code:

```
Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first look at this `stack-overflow` answer: Visit reference - [find open-ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248775/cmake-not-able-to-find-openssl-library).

If you're on Linux-OS - this worked!. You can install `open-ssl` via terminal as:

- `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

Otherwise, you have to solved as follows: You have to open the `CMakeCache.txt` file in `source-directory`, find the line:

> - OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND

Visit reference: [find-open-ssl](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/FindOpenSSL.html), then change it to with your openssl location inside source-directory as follows:

> - OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include

For further learing in detail: Visit reference- [open-ssl-during-cmake](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak/issues/1621)