# Error using cmake to configure and build Axiros AXACT: OpenSSL Directory Not Found

Tags: cmake, openssl

I am running 64-bit Mint operating system using the Linux 5.4.0-58-generic kernel, and the OpenSSL version is v1.1.1f.

Tried both setting external environment variable `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` to `/usr/lib/ssl` and the cmake variable `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` to `/usr/lib/ssl` and the same error persists.  I set `OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR` on the cmake configuration variables and it removed the "OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR" error.  I am not sure where `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` should be or how the folder structure should look like (I have tried searching for the directory for a while now) so that would be great to know as well.

Here is the error I get:

```
-- Could NOT find Lua (missing: LUA_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:447 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:74 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: How have you installed OpenSSL? By using a package manager, or by building it from sources?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I do not remember.  Should I reinstall at all using the package manager or building from sources?

Comment: You should give proper `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` hint for point to OpenSSL **installation prefix**. Directory `/usr/lib/ssl` is definitely wrong for that purpose. Proper prefix should point to the directory, which has `include/openssl/ssl.h` in it, and also should have `lib/` subdirectory with the OpenSSL library.

Comment: I figured out what the issue was.  The program was not just asking for openssl, but also the development package which has the includes.  I did not have them, so installing the necessary packages fixed the issue.  (OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR must've been set when installing the packages)  Thank you!

Comment: So, the problem is basically to understand what CMake wants from you by printing given message. The [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248775/cmake-not-able-to-find-openssl-library) has the same intention. If it doesn't have an answer describing the Linux Mint packages needed to be installed, then feel free to add your own answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will contribute.